# Applying multiple business rules to determine final result using Scala List operations

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here after the Gamer and Dealer have drawn all their cards (in a game of blackjack) I need to decide who won the game. The highest player with points not over 21 wins, if both have the same points the Gamer wins.

So I have this Scala code:

```
    def determineWinner(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Player = {
      List(gamer, dealer).filter(_.points <= blackJack).maxBy(_.points)
    }
```

Questions:

- Can we improve the code above? is there a more idiomatic approach?
- How could i change the above code to explicitly deal with the case of when both have equal points?

Complete code here: https://bitbucket.org/jameskingconsulting/blackjack-scala/src/master/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxBy` explicitly returns the first max value, so putting the gamer first in the list ensures the gamer will always win ties. Just be careful not to use a collection with a non-deterministic iteration order, like a Set.

I think this is fairly concise and idiomatic code, aside from the fact that you don't handle both players busting. I might consider making the rules a little more explicit like the following, but it would be a close call that I would discuss with colleagues:

```
if (!busted(gamer) && (gamer.points >= dealer.points || busted(dealer)))
  Some(gamer)
else if (!busted(dealer))
  Some(dealer)
else
  None
```

Comment: thanks, the '_.points <= blackJack' where blackjack is int value 21 covers the busted case